# Why is my "where" statement not working when it's being designated?

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently trying to write an SQL statement which does the following;

"*The sales department now uses the abbreviation SL instead of SA. Change the abbreviation in the job description. Select all employees of the sales department except Taylor. Sort by the total.*"

This is the code i'm currently trying to run, any advice?

```
SELECT CONCAT("first_name","", "last_name")
FROM employees NOT "Taylor"
WHERE = "sl"
ORDER by verschil DESC
```

Comment: First of all, please tag the DBMS you are using. Second: That's quite a strange order of statements in your query. What do you expect a statement like `FROM employees NOT "Taylor"` or `WHERE = "sl"` to do.

Comment: ANSI SQL has double quotes for identifiers, such as column names. And single quotes are used for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated which DMBS you are using. But you have a few obvious syntax errors.

1. You need to specify the column name for the department in the WHERE clause such as

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE column_name = "sl" ORDER BY...;
```

2. I would suggest you also include your logic for excluding the person called "Taylor" inside the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming you're working with postgresql, secondly you're trying to get all employees name from employees table who are from sales department (you need to replace column_name1 with the actual name of the column where 'SL' value is inserted, replace column_name2 by the name of the column by which you want the result to sort on).

```
select first_name, last_name 
from employees
where first_name<>'Taylor' and last_name<>'Taylor' and column_name1='SL'
order by column_name2
```

Answer (score -1):

This should fix your issue :

```
SELECT first_name," ",last_name
FROM employees 
WHERE = "sl" and NOT "Taylor"
ORDER by verschil DESC
```

Comment: In what DBMS is an expression like `WHERE = "sl" and NOT "Taylor"` supposed to work?

Comment: In RDBMS and one more thing you mention SQL question right

Comment: @Aleem can you [edit] your post specially to more explain why this should fix the issue of the question ?

Comment: `WHERE = "sl" and NOT "Taylor"` is not valid standard SQL syntax so I doubt, that this will work in any RDBMS implementing standard SQL syntax ...